# Rust and Gzipped files

Tags: rust, gzip

I'm a Python and Golang dev and have recently started learning Rust. My current project involves processing hundreds of gzipped log files, each with hundreds of thousands of JSON entries, one JSON per line. My initial attempts were surprisingly slow. Investigating this, I noticed that Python 3 performs significantly faster than the Rust implementation, even when compiled in release mode. Am I doing something wrong?

Below is my Rust implementation:

```rust
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use std::fs::File;
use libflate::gzip::Decoder;

fn main() {
    let path = "/path/to/input.json.gz";
    process_file(path);
}

fn process_file(path: &str) {
    let x = BufReader::new(Decoder::new(File::open(path).unwrap()).unwrap())
        .lines()
        .count();

    println!("Found {} events", x);
}
```

Here is the significantly faster Python code that does the same thing:

```py
import gzip

def main():
    path = "/path/to/input.json.gz";
    process_file(path)

def process_file(path):
    with gzip.open(path) as fp:
        count = 0
        for _ in fp:
            count += 1
    print(f"Found {count} events")
```

Thank you for reading and making it this far.

Comment: Can you give us some examples of the timing here? Is it worth testing different gzip back-ends like [flate2](https://crates.io/crates/flate2)?

Comment: I did some testing. Each test used the same gzipped file of 100,000 JSON lines.

Python: 759ms
Flate2 [zlib-ng-compat]: 1316ms
Flate2 [default]: 20919ms
Libflate: 31825ms

I didn't know about the `zlib-ng-compat` feature. Thank you for pointing it out to me.

Comment: If the Python version is actually C in the back-end it's going to perform very well, so you'll need to find an equally optimized Rust version to compare it to. Are you comparing a release build of your Rust code vs. Python, or debug vs. Python? The debug builds can be *dramatically* slower.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this with a big gzipped file and for me Rust with flate2 is much faster than Python 3.8.5 (Rust: 9 seconds, Rut w/zlib-ng-compat: 7 seconds, Python: 25 seconds).

Answer (score 3):

For maximum performance try using the [`flate2`](https://crates.io/crates/flate2) crate with the `zlib-ng` backend.